# SupportMapFragment - cannot cast from Fragment to MapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Trying to put together a little MapFragment in an activity I'm building, but am having some trouble getting it all to work.  I know that the Maps api and Play services are both installed correctly, as I did the test tutorial and everything worked fine.

Following the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map), I'm running into the following problem:  In my setUpMapIfNeeded method, I can either use `getFragmentManager()` or `getSupportFragmentManager()`.  When I use the `getFragmentManager()`, Eclipse is cool with it but when I run, I get a `NoSuchMethodError` saying that the method is undefined.  When I opt for `getSupportFragmentManager()`, Eclipse doesn't like it and gives me the error "Cannot cast from Fragment to MapFragment".  So what's the deal?  Any suggestions?

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    //Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        mMap = ((MapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        if (mMap != null) {
            //do things to the map
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(LOCATION).title(EXTRA_URL));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LOCATION,15));
            mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if there's any other code I can provide and I'll be happy to post it quickly.

Comment: do you have the class attribute in the R.id.map?
`class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"`

Answer (score 82, accepted):

> I can either use getFragmentManager() or getSupportFragmentManager().

There should be no debate here. If `getSupportFragmentManager()` is available to you, then you are using the Android Support package's backport of fragments, and this is the method that you must use.

> When I opt for getSupportFragmentManager(), Eclipse doesn't like it and gives me the error "Cannot cast from Fragment to MapFragment".

That is because you should not be using `MapFragment`. You are using the Android Support package's backport of fragments, and therefore you must use `SupportMapFragment`.

Comment: gosh i feel really silly now.  i was definitely aware of that, but apparently hadn't changed them all to SupportMapFragment.  I was importing MapFragment and not SupportMapFragment. Thanks!  Solved my problem.

Comment: Sometimes silly mistakes helps others (probably newbies) to grasp a concept, so never feel too silly ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is what i had to do, because i was working under level 11;

```
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

    public class MapaActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mapa);

        map =  ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapa)).getMap();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hey simply add v4 jar to your libs folder and add to build 
then in your Fragment page just import

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

you may able to extends FragmentActivity

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener{

}

and it also access getSupportFragmentManager();

SupportMapFragment fm =(SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

Answer (score 0):

Change your dependencies to:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
```