# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i need help. Im trying to start an app with Google Maps V2 integrated. On my Samsung Galaxy S2 with JellyBean it is working and on my fathers' S3 as well. But on a HTC Desire and some others it doesn't. I couldn't find out what I'am doing wrong.

Logcat:

```
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:876)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:634)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1650)
at GoogleMaps.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/
at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:466)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:544)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
```

The XML-File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.34" >

   <fragment // This is line 15
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what version of Android the desire has ?

Comment: thats the problem you have to use SupportMapFragment, in place of MapFragment !

Comment: brow now i have another problem. I need an alternative to this line of code:
map = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

because FragmentManager was introduced in API 11.

Comment: Found it out by myself for the people who face the same problem:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-compatibility-working-with-fragments/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004137/supportmapfragment-cannot-cast-from-fragment-to-mapfragment

Comment: sorry, i was online :)

Comment: my bad, yes offline :), was = wasn't ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `SupportMapFragment`.

```
<fragment
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
...
```

Your class must extend `FragmentActivity.`

Also make sure you imported the below

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;  
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
```

Comment: Thanks man I wasted so much time on this and this couple of code made it work again thank you (Y)

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps V2 supports Android version 2.2+

Google Maps V2 require installed on the your device Google Maps and Google Play Service. If your device does not contains this application your app does not work.

HTC desire by default working under Android version 2.1

Comment: it just requires play services maps are'nt neccesary.