# Android Studio Google Map Incompatible Types Error

Tags: google-maps, android-studio

I am trying to set the Google Map in an Android Studio Project but facing incompatible types error even after applying different options couldn't get rid of it. Thanks for your time and guidance

Screenshot of error

[image]

Logcate report

```
Error:(454, 88) error: incompatible types: Fragment cannot be converted to SupportMapFragment
```

XML code

```
<fragment
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/map2"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Activity code

```
public class Search extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback

private void initializeMap()
{

   SupportMapFragment map = ((SupportMapFragment)     getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map2)).getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change this line

```
SupportMapFragment map = ((SupportMapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map2)).getMapAsync(this);
```

to

```
SupportMapFragment map = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map2)).getMapAsync(this);
```

For more information, check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004137/supportmapfragment-cannot-cast-from-fragment-to-mapfragment)